How to set launch target in VSCode with a makefile?
I'm new to makefiles and was trying to get it working with vscode but I'm not sure how to set the launch target?

From what I understand when I press F5 vscode will start at the "all" rule in the makefile and then go to build and main which will build the main.exe?  In vscode when I click on launch target nothing shows up.

I think "launch target" means that the built executable will run. take a look on this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference.

Thx for reply.  I went to bed in frustration and the next day the sidepanel was bugging out.  So I deleted everything and reinstalled the make tools in vscode and its working now.  >_<

Please close the question, if it is solved.
